# Determine number of times and how long a user is logged in using Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, session

Is it possible to find out how many times and how long a user is logged into a site using Google Analytics?

Answer (score 3):

May be the **session level custom variable** is enough for you.  You can use a custom variable scoped to the session level for user login status.

Async Snippet:

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
      1,             // This custom var is set to slot #1.  Required parameter.
      'User Type',   // The name of the custom variable.  Required parameter.
      'Member',      // Sets the value of "User Type" to "Member" or "Visitor" depending on status.  Required parameter.
       2             // Sets the scope to session-level.  Optional parameter.
   ]);
```

You can find more information [in this page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables).